# Inheritance mind boggler

Tags: java, inheritance

Say there is a class Foo, and Bar is it's subclass (Bar extends foo), and the following is declared:

```
 Foo foo = new Bar(1)
 Bar bar = (Bar) foo
```

The declared type of foo is Foo and it's actual type is Bar
The declared type of bar is Bar, but what is it's actual type?

Comment: `bar` is just `foo` cast to a `Bar` type which means it's type is `Bar` assuming the cast even worked

Comment: You can test this yourself using instanceof e.g. `if (foo instanceof Bar) System.out.println("foo is Bar")`

Comment: Imagine `Foo` is `Car` and `Bar` is `Porsche`. Can you construct a `Car` which is just a generic thing that has 4 wheels? Not really. Can you construct (order) a Porsche? Yes. Now you want a `Car`, so you get a Porsche delivered. Then you say: I want to use it like a Porsche, well -- if it is a Porsche it will function that way, otherwise it will not meet your expectations raising an exception of some sort, like failing to overtake a truck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual type of `bar` is... `Bar`.

The JVM will throw an exception if casting to `Bar` is not possible. Please be aware that `foo` and `bar` only store a reference to an object. Passing and casting the reference doesn't modify pointed object.

It's different than in C++, when you can cast an object when passing it by value.